# YouTube API v3, How to PUT fileDetails

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I want to upload or update a video on my Youtbe channel, using Python and API v3. It works well. But the uploaded file appears as "File Raw: Unknown".
I want it to appear in "File Raw" the name of the video file I uploaded.
How do I change the value of the "fileName" field in API v3?

I want it to appear "File Raw: myvideo.mp4".

With examples:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#update_a_video

It's not possible.

Help me please.
Thank you very much.

The code is that of the links, I try to add or modify this part when updating a video:

```
videos_list_fileDetails = videos_list_response["items"][0]["fileDetails"]

videos_list_fileDetails["fileName"]="myvideo.mp4"


videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
part='fileDetails',
body=dict(
    fileDetails=videos_list_fileDetails,
    id=idvideo
    )).execute()
```

No error, but not working

Comment: Provide the code you have written.

Comment: I have included a part of the code, which affects, the rest is similar to the link.